# Interaction problem between WCF service and ASP.NET sites with cookieless session, different subdomains

Tags: asp.net, wcf, session, cookieless

I have several ASP.NET sites, hosted on the same domain (different subdomains) and working via HTTPS.

I have WCF service, hosted on the same domain.

I have a separate state server for sessions.

All sites use cookieless session (if someone asks why - i will reply later, but it's a 'must')

On my sites, I use grid components from Telerik (but actually it does not matter) that ask for data from WCF service and must be filled with this data.

The problems are:

1) I cannot manage to make POST request to WCF service from javascript: for some reason it's always either GET or OPTIONS (no matter if I use Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy invoke or just a plain jquery AJAX request). It happens even if I indicate COOKIE mode, not cookieless. Maybe because of this I am getting "405 Method not allowed" error - WCF is set for POST request, but the site sends GET...

2) I cannot manage to retrieve SESSION from my websites! I tried approach, that I found, but WCF always uses OWN session, instead of 'connecting' to existing ASP.NET session, despite on ASP.NET compatibility mode. I need SESSION to exchange data between my sites and WCF service

3) I don't have idea currently, how to manage security when exchanging data between mentioned ones, in the light of above-mentioned problems...

4) I don't know exactly, how web.config for WCF service should look like in my case, because I've seen tons of different variants, but all for some simple cases.

Would be really appreciated for the help! I'm stuck for 2 or 3 weeks already, far behind the plan, but nothing still works... I can see there are some pieces of info about similar problems, but I'm afraid to miss some small thing - in web.config or method attribute or IIS setting, etc - and f... up everything.

Too many problems and too few time for experiments :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one: WCF is **not** ASP.NET - so therefore, you **cannot** share session state between ASP.NET sites and WCF.

If you need to share anything between the two worlds, it should be stored in a database both sides can access.

You don't provide a whole lot of information about what you're trying to do... can you explain to us what that WCF service should do (or show us the WCF service contract)?? Also - what are the requirements for calling that service? You talk about POST requests... are you trying to create a RESTful service to be called from Javascript?

**Update:** while it's true that WCF is not ASP.NET, and the two basically don't use the same mechanisms for session state etc., it appears to be possible to configure WCF services (when hosted in IIS) to be able to access ASP.NET session state.

See Wenlong Dong's blog post on [Using ASP.NET sessions from WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx). From his blog post, I don't see whether this will work in a cookieless environment, however.....

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the things a little bit! About what I am trying to do. Well, we have a huge corporate site with hundreds of entities. Most of these entities are represented with grids (list of entities, their events, etc.) Could be totally dozen of thousands records per view with link to detailed info, ajax popups, etc. Of course, we use paging :) We use Microsoft Enterprise Library and follow its rule, having DataBase provider, Controller and Entity. That is our Business Logic. So, we had an object data source, binding Entity to the grid. And working 'server-side'.

Comment: Now we decided to use client-side binding and services, filtering, no postbacks, no page reload (ajax panels are not very reliable, so we would prefer not to use them). So - client-side sends request to WCF service with some grid parameters (starting row, number of row, etc) and WCF service should send response to fill the grid.

Comment: Actully, it worked somehow already, but then it appeared that would be also good to share the session of sites for WCF service in order it could store some data there (in some cases we most likely will need this, but if it's for sure not possible without some serious stuff, like storing session in the database - slow-down, then... )

Comment: thanks. I've seen this article before. But if I got it right - it's rather for sharing WCF session between different requests, not sharing ASP.NET session with WCF service... And - anyway, no anything about cookieless mode... :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with moving WCF service under web, so will have a WCF service PER web site

Answer (score -1):

use this link When you are using silverlight application With Wcf Service then for coockie less url
http://mithunpatra.blogspot.in/2015/05/coockie-less-urls-to-access-wcf.html

Answer (score -1):

When you are using silverlight application With Wcf Service then for coockie less url
http://mithunpatra.blogspot.in/2015/05/coockie-less-urls-to-access-wcf.html

Comment: Please don't post links to external sites, post the relevant code and explanation here and then cite other sites as a source.